How to block internet access for WireGuard clients but allow LAN? (and deny connections between clients)
I have a WireGuard VPN server. All clients connect to anywhere from its wg0 interface. I need to block internet access for all traffic coming from this interface except LAN IP address range. At the same time, the host machine should have access to anywhere. I also need to block traffic between clients. How can I do that? I guess I need to configure PostUp and PostDown config values but I have no enough experience to do that properly. My current settings are the following:
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

What should I add here to properly configure iptables on up and down?
PS: I know about the option to configure the AllowedIPs setting on clients. But the issue is that if the client changes this setting to 0.0.0.0/0, all the traffic will go through the tunnel. But I need to block this possibility on the server level.

You'd minimally need something like the following (if the server's WireGuard interface was named wg0, and LAN address range was 192.168.200.0/24):
PreUp = iptables -I FORWARD 1 -o wg0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
PreUp = iptables -I FORWARD 2 -i wg0 -d 192.168.200.0/24 -j ACCEPT
PreUp = iptables -I FORWARD 3 -i wg0 -j REJECT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -d 192.168.200.0/24 -j ACCEPT
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j REJECT

This configures the server's firewall to:

Allow the forwarding of return traffic back out its WireGuard interface (wg0).
Allow the forwarding of traffic from its WireGuard interface to its LAN (192.168.200.0/24).
Block the forwarding of all other incoming WireGuard traffic.


Once you start building up a firewall ruleset for a server, however, you may find it more convenient to define all your firewall rules in once place, and run them once on server boot -- rather than adding & removing them ad-hoc through WireGuard up/down scripts. Plus you may want to further lock down network access to your WireGuard server (or enforce further restrictions on exactly which WireGuard clients can access which services on your LAN).
For example, if you start with the Simple Stateful Firewall iptables ruleset from Arch Linux wiki, you might use a ruleset like the following to lock down your WireGuard server to block access except to its WireGuard port (UDP port 51820), and block forwarding new connections except from its WireGuard interface (wg0) to its LAN (192.168.200.0/24):
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:TCP - [0:0]
:UDP - [0:0]
:fw-interfaces - [0:0]
:fw-open - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
-A INPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j fw-interfaces
-A FORWARD -j fw-open
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable
-A UDP -p udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
-A fw-open -i wg0 -d 192.168.200.0/24 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

Another example of this is the nftables ruleset from the How to Set Up a WireGuard Jumphost article, which locks down the WireGuard server so that it blocks network access except to its WireGuard port, and limits specific WireGuard clients to accessing only specific network services on its LAN.
